# Does anyone know a way to have the same world on 2 computers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I Want to know if there is a way to have the same world on 2 computers and say I edit the world on one computer and then go to the other and that edit I made on the first computer is on the second computer. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you provide on which OS your computers are (Windows, Linux,...) and if they are on the same network?

Answer (score 1):

The minecraft wiki has a [tutorial on how to synchronize worlds using Dropbox and symbolics links](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Saved_data_Dropbox_guide_saves_only) for example. You must have a good bandwidth though.

Remember to backup your saves somewhere before doing this...

Comment: Same also works using Google Drive (what I use), OneDrive, Box, Mega and other cloud services that support syncing with a local file system. The story is a bit different on Linux, sadly. I use RCloneSync for Google Drive on Debian, but it is much more difficult to set up than "install, login, done" on Windows and it has some problems and special cases.

Comment: If you run out of free space in Dropbox (2 GB), Google Drive (15 GB), or whatever other cloud service you use, it may be cheaper to invest in a private Minecraft Realm than to buy extra space.  However, Drive's smallest plan is surprisingly cheap, so I'm not sure a Realm is actually worth it for most people.  OTOH Realms does give you true multiplayer hosting, which you definitely won't get out of Dropbox/Drive/etc.